# how do i do that format what should i use

Tags: mysql, sql

schema:

```
create table candidates ( 
id int primary key, position 
varchar not null, 
salary int not null 
); 

insert into candidates values (3, 'senior', 35000); 
insert into candidates values (4, 'junior', 8000); 
insert into candidates values (5, 'senior', 30000); 
insert into candidates values (6, 'senior', 25000); 
insert into candidates values (7, 'junior', 30000); 
insert into candidates values (8, 'senior', 50000); 
insert into candidates values (9, 'senior', 30000); 
insert into candidates values (10, 'junior', 7000); 
insert into candidates values (11, 'junior', 8000); 
insert into candidates values (12, 'senior', 33000); 
insert into candidates values (13, 'junior', 5000); 
insert into candidates values (14, 'senior', 47000); 
insert into candidates values (15, 'junior', 12000);
```

[image]

Comment: What problem are you facing? What is not working? And please do not add external images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT 
MAX(CASE WHEN position = 'senior' THEN salary ELSE 0 END) 'senior',
  MAX(CASE WHEN position = 'junior' THEN salary ELSE 0 END) 'junior'
FROM candidates
```

| senior | junior |
| --- | --- |
| 50000 | 30000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QZcsWyS9)